# Why is this giving me result in pounds every time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
weight = input("Weight: ")
unit = input("(K)g sau (L)bs: ")

if str(unit) == "l" or "L":
    print(weight * 3)
else str(starea) == "k" or "K":
    print(weight * 0.45)
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002504/476). Also, `str(unit)` is pretty superfluous, since `unit` is by definition a string already. On the contrary, you need to do `int(weight)` if you want to treat it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't typecasting the input with int() in this scenario

This is why python thinks that your input is '36' instead of 36

When you do '36'*3 what actually happens is that '36' gets repeated 3 times so the output would be '363636'